# What other cactus can I plant in the same box with my FairyCastle Cactus?

Tags: plant-recommendations, cactus, repotting

I’m planning on planting my fairy cactus in a new box but I’d like to also plant a second cactus with it, I really want to get a lady finger cactus but I don’t know what cacti are plantable next to my fair castle. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Daisy, a picture of the new box and your fairy cactus would help